# Postmortem for the event "Gamdev's Septemberbash 2021 Showcase!"

Tags: discussion

The recent event [Gamdev's Septemberbash 2021 Showcase!](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/show-us-your-in-development-game-gamdevs-septemberbash-2021-showcase) came to an end after one month of being active.

We'd like to know a bit more how we can improve this event in the future.

- What did you like about it?
- What did you dislike about it?
- What could be done better next time?
- Any other thoughts about it?

Please phrase your answer(s) in a way that makes it clear why folks would upvote or downvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a great idea. It provides an outlet for people to promote their work so they don't get tempted to try to do it on the main page and earn a bunch of downvotes and spam-flags for self-promotion (not that much of a problem, but it happens occasionally). I also find it interesting to see what the other members of the community work on.

But I, for one, did not even notice this until it was over. I guess I am not the only one, considering that it only received 3 entries (one of them self-deleted by the author for reasons they kept to themselves). So advertising this better might help.

Although I would not have participated anyway that month, because I couldn't think of anything I did during that timeframe which would be worth showing off. I am a hobbyist game developer and I am currently "between projects".

Comment: Thanks for the answer; _"So advertising this better might help."_ Do you have suggestions to improve this? We used the "event" site feature and so a link to the event post was posted there for a whole month. This might not be as visible for mobile users as it is for desktop users.

Comment: The event is here again ;)